# How to fix "ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64" using C++, CMake and Tensorflow?

Tags: c++, macos, tensorflow, cmake

I created a test project in C ++ using TensorFlow with CMake. But I have an error:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I think, I have an error in my CMake files. When I try compile via the terminal with `gcc tensortest.cpp -ltensorflow -o tf`, everything works fine.

I have two CMake files.

FindTensorFlow.cmake:

```
# Locates the tensorFlow library and include directories.
include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
unset(TENSORFLOW_FOUND)

find_path(TensorFlow_INCLUDE_DIR
        NAMES
        tensorflow
        HINTS

        /usr/local/include/tensorflow)

find_library(TensorFlow_LIBRARY
        NAMES
        libtensorflow_framework.1.14.0.dylib
        libtensorflow_framework.1.dylib
        libtensorflow_framework.dylib
        libtensorflow.1.14.0.dylib
        libtensorflow.1.dylib
        libtensorflow.dylib
        HINTS
        /usr/local/lib)

# set TensorFlow_FOUND
find_package_handle_standard_args(TensorFlow DEFAULT_MSG TensorFlow_INCLUDE_DIR TensorFlow_LIBRARY)

# set external variables for usage in CMakeLists.txt
if(TENSORFLOW_FOUND)
  set(TensorFlow_LIBRARIES ${TensorFlow_LIBRARY})
  set(TensorFlow_INCLUDE_DIRS ${TensorFlow_INCLUDE_DIR})
endif()

# hide locals from GUI
mark_as_advanced(TensorFlow_INCLUDE_DIR TensorFlow_LIBRARY)
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(TensorFlowTest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/")

find_package(TensorFlow REQUIRED)
include_directories(${TensorFlow_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${TensorFlow_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(TensorFlowTest main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(TensorFlowTest ${TensorFlow_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${TensorFlow_LIBRARIES})
```

And one main.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tensorflow/c/c_api.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello from TensorFlow C library version %s\n", TF_Version());
    return 0;
}
```

When reload project, I have a CMake message:

```
-- Found TensorFlow: /usr/local/include  
-- Configuring done
WARNING: Target "TensorFlowTest" requests linking to directory "/usr/local/include".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/neikr/CLionProjects/TensorFlowTest/cmake-build-debug
```

And when compiling:

```
Scanning dependencies of target TensorFlowTest
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/TensorFlowTest.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable TensorFlowTest
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_TF_Version", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [TensorFlowTest] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/TensorFlowTest.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/TensorFlowTest.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [TensorFlowTest] Error 2
```

## Update

I tried `make` with `VERBOSE=1` and I get this output:

```
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake -S/Users/neikr/CLionProjects/TensorFlowTest -B/Users/neikr/CLionProjects/TensorFlowTest --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /Users/neikr/CLionProjects/TensorFlowTest/CMakeFiles /Users/neikr/CLionProjects/TensorFlowTest/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/TensorFlowTest.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/TensorFlowTest.dir/depend
cd /Users/neikr/CLionProjects/TensorFlowTest && /Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /Users/neikr/CLionProjects/TensorFlowTest /Users/neikr/CLionProjects/TensorFlowTest /Users/neikr/CLionProjects/TensorFlowTest /Users/neikr/CLionProjects/TensorFlowTest /Users/neikr/CLionProjects/TensorFlowTest/CMakeFiles/TensorFlowTest.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/TensorFlowTest.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/TensorFlowTest.dir/build
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable TensorFlowTest
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/TensorFlowTest.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++  -g -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  CMakeFiles/TensorFlowTest.dir/main.cpp.o  -o TensorFlowTest -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib/libtensorflow_framework.1.14.0.dylib 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_TF_Version", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [TensorFlowTest] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/TensorFlowTest.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Also, I tried adding `message("TensorFlow_LIBRARIES: ${TensorFlow_LIBRARIES}")` to the end of my CMake and I get this message:

```
TensorFlow_LIBRARIES: /usr/local/lib/libtensorflow_framework.1.14.0.dylib
```

Comment: Please include verbose flags in your calls for more detailed error info.  Check your cmake cache or use `ccmake` to check for incorrect paths.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, and great first question! I think you are getting *include directories* confused with *link libraries*. You should only include the header file directories here: `include_directories(${TensorFlow_INCLUDE_DIRS})`. Likewise, you only need to add the libraries (`_LIBRARIES`) here: `target_link_libraries(TensorFlowTest ${TensorFlow_LIBRARIES})`.

Comment: It would be helpful to see if the TensorFlow libraries were *actually* found. Consider adding message("TensorFlow_LIBRARIES: ${TensorFlow_LIBRARIES}") to the end of your CMake. Or, as suggested, please add the output of `make VERBOSE=1` to your question post.

Comment: @squareskittles I changed include directories on `include_directories(${TensorFlow_INCLUDE_DIRS}`. But I do not understand what libraries need to be added.

Comment: Based on your print-out from the `message()` command, it is more clear. The `find_library()` call only finds *one* library `libtensorflow_framework.1.14.0.dylib`, which is expected behavior. Once `find_library()` finds *one* library, it stops the search. If you want to also find `libtensorflow.dylib`, which may help with your link error, you have to specify *another* `find_library()` call, using a different `TensorFlow_` variable.

Comment: @squareskittles thank you. I didn't know that. I fixed it, now works.

Comment: Ok, great! I expanded my comment into an answer, with a documentation link. Glad this helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your print-out from the `message()` command, it is more clear what is going on. In your `FindTensorFlow.cmake` file, the [`find_library()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_library.html) call only finds *one* library (`libtensorflow_framework.1.14.0.dylib`), which is expected behavior:

> Once one of the calls succeeds the result variable will be set and stored in the cache so that no call will search again.
>
> When more than one value is given to the `NAMES` option this command by default will consider one name at a time and search every directory for it.

Thus, once `find_library()` finds the `libtensorflow_framework` library, the search *stops*. If you want to also find `libtensorflow.dylib`, which may help with your link error, you have to specify another `find_library()` call, using a different `TensorFlow_` variable. So changing that section of your `FindTensorFlow.cmake` to something like this should help:

```
find_library(TensorFlow_LIBRARY
        NAMES
        libtensorflow.1.14.0.dylib
        libtensorflow.1.dylib
        libtensorflow.dylib
        HINTS
        /usr/local/lib)

find_library(TensorFlow_FRAMEWORK_LIBRARY
        NAMES
        libtensorflow_framework.1.14.0.dylib
        libtensorflow_framework.1.dylib
        libtensorflow_framework.dylib
        HINTS
        /usr/local/lib)

# set TensorFlow_FOUND
find_package_handle_standard_args(TensorFlow DEFAULT_MSG 
    TensorFlow_INCLUDE_DIR 
    TensorFlow_LIBRARY 
    TensorFlow_FRAMEWORK_LIBRARY
)
```